# overbrace in Context

Tags: context, annotations, underbrace

In LaTeX and Co, I can reach the following by using `\overbrace` and `mathclap`: [image: Expample of overbrace and mathclap]

The source creating this example is:

```
\[
E(\vec{r},t) \propto e^{
    \overbrace{
        i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega t)
    }^{\mathclap{\text{Phase}}}}
\]
```

How can I achieve that in Context?

Comment: No I will change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\clap` command in ConTeXt is aware of math mode and no separate commands are necessary for the use in formulas and normal text.

```
\starttext

\startformula
E(\vec{r},t) \propto e^{
    \overbrace{
        i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega t)
    }^{\text{Phase}}}
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image]